# Add animation to google map marker swift

Tags: swift, google-maps, animation

I am using the google map, and I added a marker which always locate at the center of the map while I dragging the map. Now I want to add a animation to that marker that when I dragging the map, the marker will move up a little bit. So I add code,

```
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.marker?.iconView?.transform =     CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -150)
        })
```

to mapView(didChange position), but nothing happened.

What should I do to add the animation to that marker?